# Cannot pass a sub-interface as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, parameters, interface

I have the following interface hierarchy:

```
public interface IActor { ... }
public interface IHealthUser : IActor { ... }
```

and a third interface:

```
public interface IAction { void Perform(IActor caster) }
```

Why is the following not legal and can I get around it somehow?

```
public class HealthPotion : IAction
{
    public void Perform(IHealthUser caster) { ... }
}
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled "'HealthPotion' does not implement member 'IAction.Perform(IActor)'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contract defined by `IAction` states that you can `Perform` the action on any `IActor`. *Any* IActor. Not only `IHealthUser`. What your `HealthPotion` tries to do is only implement a subset of `IAction`, meaning to perform its task only on a subset of `IActor`s. That's not what the `IAction` interface states.

If you want a specific `IAction` to be able to restrict the type of `IActor` it applies to, you can do it using generic constraints:

```
public interface IAction<TAppliesTo> where TAppliesTo : IActor
{
    void Perform(TAppliesTo appliesTo);
}

public class UniversalAction : IAction<IActor>
{
   public void Perform (IActor anyone) {}
}

public class HealthPotion : IAction<IHealthUser>
{
   public void Perform (IHealthUser healthUserOnly){}
}
```

Comment: Of course! I was stuck in the mindset "IHealthUser is a derived interface, it should work!", when what I actually was doing was making the IAction implementation more restricted. You put it well, and the generic option work wonders.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the same signature as your interface defines. You are using **IActor** in the interface but then you are using **IHealthUser** in the implementation of **IAction** interface. You should implement the **Perform** with the **IActor** parameter. It can be called however with class that implements **IHealthUser**.